# HP ProLiant DL380 added disks, but FreeNAS doesn't detect them

Tags: hp-proliant, truenas

I have a HP ProLiant DL380 server and just inserted some extra disks (everything is hot swap), but the server doesn't seem to detect them. I tried `camcontrol rescan all`, but to no avail, it is just as if the disks aren't there at all.

No lights go on on the disks either.

What can I do to get these disks to be detected? I want to avoid rebooting the NAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be hot-swap but that's for existing arrays, if you've literally just added new disks then you need to either add them to an existing array and logical disk/s or create a new array and carve that into logical disks.

I don't know freenas but does it come with HP's drivers pre-built in or can they be added (not sure it's a supported config). The only ways to configure your array/s is either via the HP drivers/tools (look for a bit of code called 'hpacucli' or similar) or via one of the bios methods that have to be done using a reboot.

Comment: Indeed, I am physically adding disks. I am looking now for that `hpacucli` tool.

Comment: Found a old version of the tool, doesn't seem to work; I am afraid a reboot has to be done.

Comment: Can you not install the new version if it's available - sorry to be dim but I can never remember the base OS inside FreeNAS, is it BSD? if so there may well be updated drivers/tools for that on HP's site, let us know ok.

Comment: It is FreeBSD, and HP is not supplying any drivers whatsoever for that OS.

Comment: @BartFriederichs - Boo HP Boo :( - you'll have to do this via a reboot then sorry.